# How to set multiple styles for one Div?

Tags: css, navbar

I am having some problems with my CSS external style sheet. I am trying to make a unordered list into navigation bar. I am attempting to do this by adding multiple styles to my navbar div but none of the changes are having any effect on the page when they are inside the navbar div.

```
#navbar{
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest them like that, try this:

The space between tags/identifiers means the right option is inside the left.

```
#navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Depending on what kind of CSS preprocessor the OP is using, their original code might well be valid.

Comment: Fair point, but that information wasn't provided, so I have to assume its vanilla and the syntax is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Just so I understand for the future why is it that you need to format it in this way?.

Comment: This is simply how css is written. If you want to specify the unordered lists only in nav, you need to write "nav" followed by a space, followed by "ul", and if you want to specify list items only in "ul"s that are in a nav, you follow that by a space, then "li"

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're currently using is only valid if you're using the Sass/SCSS preprocessor. While Sass is super-awesome, you'd probably be better off using vanilla CSS for now to build a solid CSS foundation. But whenever you want to get some exposure to Sass, check out their docs here: http://sass-lang.com/guide.

In the meantime, this should work for you:

```
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}
```